# Ruby class set/get

Tags: ruby, get, set

What is wrong with this `set/get`?

```
class Pupil
  def name
    @name
  end

  def name=(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def age
    @age
  end

  def age=(age)
    @age
  end
end
```

Further on the same, if there was a child class with 3 arguments, name, age, sex, would the set get method in the child for sex only. Can you please show the set/get method and initialize in the child class.

Comment: `name` is fine. `age=` doesn't do what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
def age=(age)
    @age
  end
```

should be

```
  def age=(age)
    @age = age
  end
```

You can also make your code beautiful by replacing get/set with  attr_accessor which itself provides a getter/setter

```
 class Pupil
   attr_accessor :age,:name
 end
```

Comment: PriteshJ. Thank you. I resolved it. (Actually, I edit the additional question to my original question.)

Comment: OK, `attr_accessor` is what I was looking for. Where do you find this information in the official documentation as someone learning Ruby? I've been looking through http://ruby-doc.org/ , but it barely mentions this under `Module` (not `Class`) and even there doesn't mention terms like property, getter, setter… It's kind of hard to learn these concepts from there. Essentially I'm looking for the Ruby equivalent of the official Python tutorial – https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ .

Comment: I've answered my own question – there's an official Ruby quickstart on ruby-lang.org – https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set `@age = age`.